# Azure devops build and publish console app

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to get a console app in my current solution (mulitple projects), build it and then publish it via azure devops.
At first the build seemed to build, but was unable to create a zipfile.
Then in the publish task it started to say the path is not there.

this is (piece of) my yaml;

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: "Build MigrationRunner"
  inputs:
    solution: '**/Migration.Runner.csproj'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\RUNNER\WebApp.zip"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: "Publish artifact 'RUNNER Service'"
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\RUNNER\WebApp.zip'
    artifact: 'RUNNER'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

I am trying to get this console in the artifacts, and then in the release pipeline I will unpack it and run the console app. If you have another alternative, all good. as long as I can run the console app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the option **`/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="xxxx.zip"`** on MSBuild is not available for console app.

I used the same **`msbuildArgs`** to build a console app, the ZIP package was not generated. However, when I used the same **`msbuildArgs`** to build a web app, the ZIP package can be generated as expected.

---

When building the console app, you need to use the [Archive files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/archive-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) to compress the build output files as a ZIP package.

See below example as reference:

```yaml
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build ConsoleAppDN6'
  inputs:
    solution: '**/Migration.Runner.csproj'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutDir="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\BuildOutput"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive Build Output'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\BuildOutput'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\RUNNER\WebApp.zip'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\RUNNER\WebApp.zip'
    artifact: 'RUNNER'
```

Comment: perfect!! this works like a charm. 
Now to see how i can download it and unpack it. thnx so far!